# Instagram API call on Magento frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, api, frontend

I would like to add the last pics from my instagram in my Magento Frontend.

I've seen the IG API and there is an Endpoint for this requeriment.

Searching the web I've found examples of the call with PHP (https://gist.github.com/cosenary/2961185)

It should be pretty easy to implement in a static website but I do not have idea on how to implement in on my magento to show in my CMS, should I create a widget? There is no way to develop it in an easy way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most popular Magento Instagram Extension https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating a CMS widget (and using it as a widget instance) would be the nicest way in my opinion. You can then use it as an inline widget, or widget instance.

Another way is to create the block and template, and use custom XML layout updates to add the block to the desired entity (category, product or CMS page).

If you don't know how to do any of that, read http://alanstorm.com/new_book_no_frills_magento_layout

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video 
It explain your requirement !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMPZ5e-wswA

Comment: this is not what I need but thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a widget on a CMS page, I will use http://instafeedjs.com/ to create a custom phtml and load it as a block on the CMS page.

You can send variables with the block like for instances hashtags or userids, from who you want to grap images. If you want to show images on the product pages,